# Formatting chat messages sent by user in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I've created a websocket server in python and I have a web chat which uses that web server, the web chat box(which displays the messages sent by the user) has the height of 83px and width of 1176px.

I'd like for my users messages to be displayed horizontally along the chat box(as accordingly with the chat box size specifications) instead of the conventional list type display of messages, so it seems as if my users are completing each other's sentences.

***Further clarifying what I mean:***

userA types: "Hi my name is James"

userB types: "Of course it is"

Chatbox output: Hi my name is James Of course it is

Is there any effective method of achieving this task? Here's what I have so far, be warned, it's not much!

```
s = new WebSocket(host);

                    s.onopen = function (e) { log_msg("connected..."); };
                    s.onclose = function (e) { log_msg("connection closed."); };
                    s.onerror = function (e) { log_msg("connection error."); };
                    s.onmessage = function (e) { log_msg("message: " + e.data); };
                } catch (ex) {
```

**HTML**

```
<fieldset id="messages" class = "focus-actions""> </fieldset>
```

**More Code as requested**

```
var messages;
            var form;
            var inputBox;

            function log_msg(msg) {
                var p = document.createElement("p");
                p.innerHTML = msg;
                messages.appendChild(p);
            }

            function doInit() {
                inputBox = document.getElementById("message");
                messages = document.getElementById("messages");
                form = document.getElementById("message-form");
                var s;
                try {
                    var host = "ws://localhost:4545/";
                    if(window.location.hostname) {
                        host = "ws://" + window.location.hostname + ":4545/";
                    }

                    s = new WebSocket(host);

                    s.onopen = function (e) { log_msg("connected..."); };
                    s.onclose = function (e) { log_msg("connection closed."); };
                    s.onerror = function (e) { log_msg("connection error."); };
                    s.onmessage = function (e) { log_msg("message: " + e.data); };
                } catch (ex) {
                    log_msg("connection exception:" + ex);
                }

                form.addEventListener("submit", function (e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    s.send(inputBox.value);
                    inputBox.value = "";
                }, false);
            }
```

Comment: Are you asking about HTM/CSS layout?

Comment: I think it's more to do with the actual javascript than the html, I'll add my html source now

Comment: So, what's inside the fieldset? Do you want a separate input and output field? Also, what's the code for `log_msg`?

Comment: The messages are displayed inside the fieldset

Comment: *The messages are displayed inside the fieldset* says nothing because the [`fieldset`-tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/fieldset) groups elements, nothing more.

Comment: That (making it horizontally instead of vertically) shouldn't be a problem (although you might want to consider auto-scrolling and overflow-handling), but we need to see more code, like the `log_msg` (hopefully that explains what's inside your fieldset).

Comment: Added, more code! I haven't displayed the HTML as it's quite simple coding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your current function `log_msg`:

```js
function log_msg(msg) {
    var p = document.createElement("p");
    p.innerHTML = msg;
    messages.appendChild(p);
}
```

you are creating 'paragraph' elements which are [block-level](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements) elements (as opposed to [inline](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Inline_elements) elements).

You'd either create alternate styling rules for `p` elements in css:

```css
#messages p    { display: inline }
```

for those paragraphs (you might need to specify/override other browser-specific default styles to),

OR (more logically) you change it to create a span-element (which is inline):

In your function `log_msg`:

```js
function log_msg(msg) {
    var p = document.createElement("span");
    p.innerHTML = msg;
    messages.appendChild(p);
}
```

or simplified:

```js
function log_msg(msg) {
    messages.appendChild(document.createElement("span")).innerHTML = msg;
}  //appendChild returns child, thats why you can set innerHTML directly
```

Note that you might want to take leading and trailing whitespace (especially the lack of) into account for your `msg`! Example:

```js
msg.trim()+' '   // or for older browsers: msg.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '')+' '
```

Hope this helps!